# The proof of Caratheodory's criterion from Bogachev's book

Tags: measure-theory

I was trying to understand the proof of Caratheodory's criterion from Bogachev's book and I understood it completely except one moment one moments which I am not able to solve by myself.

[image]

[image]

I have understood that $\mu^*(E\cap A)+\mu^*(E-A)=\mu^*(E)$ holds for any $E\subset X$ and $A\in \mathcal{A}$. And the author claims that it is easy to derive this inequality for the case when $A\in \mathcal{A}_{\mu}$ just using "triangle inequality" for measure, i.e. estimate (1.5.2).

I have tried different ways but no results.

Can anyone show to me how to show this unclear step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\epsilon > 0$.  Following definition 1.5.1, since $A \in \mathcal{A}_\mu$, there exists $A' \in \mathcal{A}$ with $\mu^*(A \triangle A') < \epsilon$.  Suppose the inequality holds for $A'$.  Using the triangle inequality we can write:

$$\begin{align*} \mu^*(E \cap A) &\le \mu^*(E \cap A') + |\mu^*(E \cap A) - \mu^*(E \cap A')| \\ &\le \mu^*(E \cap A') + \mu^*((E \cap A) \triangle (E \cap A'))
\end{align*}$$
using (1.5.2).
But now you may verify that $(E \cap A) \triangle (E \cap A') \subseteq A \triangle A'$ (draw a Venn diagram if you like).  So by monotonicity of outer measure (see note on page 17) we have $\mu^*((E \cap A) \triangle (E \cap A')) \le \mu^*(A \triangle A') < \epsilon$.  Hence we have shown
$$\mu^*(E \cap A) \le \mu^*(E \cap A') + \epsilon.$$

By a similar argument you may also show that $\mu^*(E \setminus A) \le \mu(E \setminus A') + \epsilon$.  So we have
$$\mu^*(E \cap A) + \mu^*(E \setminus A) \le \mu^*(E \cap A') + \mu(E \setminus A') + 2 \epsilon = \mu^*(E) + 2\epsilon$$
since by assumption the inequality holds for $A'$.  Now since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary we must have $\mu^*(E \cap A) + \mu^*(E \setminus A) \le \mu^*(E)$ as desired.

Comment: Thanks a lot, dear Nate! Are you familiar with Bogachev's book?

Comment: I refer to it occasionally.  It's a very good reference but I am not sure it is the easiest textbook for self-study of basic measure theory.

Comment: Ok. One more time thanks for help!

Comment: Also what kind of books on Measure Theory you can advice?

Comment: Indeed, I have some difficulties with this book. Could you recommend some books on Measure Theory? Some moments of this books is extremely difficult

Comment: Not offhand, sorry.

Comment: Dear, Nate! Sorry for that but could you help me with this question? Unfortunately, no one posted even any comment. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3013020/lebesgue-and-jordan-measure-and-some-example